# Ubuntu 19.04 VM (VMWare) hanging on boot

Tags: boot, vmware, 19.04

**Context** - The VM was working fine until for some reason, during a session, I could no longer get a terminal to open within the VM so I decide to reboot and have not been successful booting the VM since.

**Symptoms** - Hangs before getting to login screen (see video below)

[error video](https://giphy.com/gifs/ZZewIEATrm9ODa0fbu/fullscreen)

**Additional Info**

- [log file](https://gist.github.com/cmseaton42/0868cb53b288780bdc87e79c40c09e30)

Anyone have any idea how I can get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
open terminal

ctl+alt+(F1 or F2 or F3 or F4 any key upto F7)

Type sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

type the password when prompted. (It will not be visible while typing.) edit the file and remove '#' located at the beginning of the following line (its 7th line)
```

## Wayland = false

```
So now the line will look like this - Wayland = false

save and close the window.

exit and restart.
```

If this does not work try updating your bios.